# Does variables creation depend on the scope?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, variables, scope

```
void someFunc()
{
int local0 = 0;
//some code
{
int local1 = 0;
//some code
}
int local2 = 0;
}
```

All three local variables will be created(allocated on the stack) at the moment of entering `someFunc`?  Or local0  will be created first, then local1, then local1 will be deleted, and then local2  created and on the exit local0 and local2 will be deleted?

Comment: `local2` will be deleted first as it is created last... but as it cannot be observed (for basic types), then the compiler might do otherwise.

Comment: @Phil1970 The principle is very general; it's called the [as-if rule.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) Also, Johy, since your function has no observable effects the compiler is free to emit no code at all for it, and ignore all calls of it. (Ah, Dr. Watson said as much already.)

Comment: It isn't mandated by any standard, but in practice the entire stack frame is allocated on entry and deallocated on return. When they are initialized is yet another question.

Comment: If you want to look into how this is done in your compiler you can use ghidra or some other decompiler. Watch out tho, your code will be optimised so unused variables will not be implemented.

Comment: `local0` will be created first. `local1` will be created when its definition is reached, and cease to exist (in the sense that use of it is either a diagnosable error or involves undefined behaviour) when its containing block ends. `local2` will not exist in code before its definition/initialisation, and will cease to exist before `local0` (a moot point as an `int` ceasing to exist has no observable side-effect in standard C++).  None of the variables exist after the function returns.  It is incorrect to say they are "deleted" since "delete" has a different specific meaning in C++

Answer (score 1):

So, this question is hard to answer in the abstract. The compiler is free to reorder your code, so long as it is equivalent to the code as written if executed sequentially. That is to say, what assembly is generated is up to the compiler.

With this specific code, and this specific code alone, a compiler performing any optimization is highly likely to realize this function is a no-op, and elide it ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z46Ws1oPz)).

That said, as general guidance, C++ does not perform mandatory variable hoisting (as with JS, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)). That is, it is at best undefined behavior (at worst, errant syntax) to use the names of variables before they are declared.

Edit: As Deduplicator mentioned in the comments, the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) formalizes how compilers can transform code. It specifies that code changes which do not affect the "observable behavior" of the program are allowed. I like John Regehr's definition of observable behavior ([here](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/232)), though it is a little tautological:

> Observable behaviors are those that are side effecting.

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention the criteria for equivalence. Specifically the terms [as-if rule](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if),  "observable behavior" and how that is defined.

Comment: Edited, @Deduplicator :) Hopefully the additional info is sufficiently informative and concise; let me know if you feel otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is defined in terms of an abstract machine. In the abstract machine the operations happen in this order:

- `local0` is created
- `local1` is created
- `local1` is destroyed
- `local2` is created

The requirements on the real machine are only that it must produce the same output that the abstract machine would . There are no requirements about how it goes about producing that output.

For this particular program the real machine might not create any of the variables since they are unused and removing them doesn't affect the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to get a handle on this if you use variables whose construction and destruction have side-effects.  Then you can see them coming and going.

So, given this:

```
class Foo
{
    int m_i;
public:
    Foo (int i) : m_i (i) { std::cout << "Foo constructor #" << i << "\n"; }
    ~Foo () { std::cout << "Foo destructor #" << m_i << "\n"; }
};
```

We can then rewrite your example as:

```
void someFunc()
{
    Foo local0 (0);
    {
        Foo local1 (1);
    }
    Foo local2 (2);
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
Foo constructor #0
Foo constructor #1
Foo destructor #1
Foo constructor #2
Foo destructor #2
Foo destructor #0
```

Which in turn makes everything clear.

As others have mentioned, if the variables are primitive types (and don't depend on each other) then the compiler is free to reorder the statements in order to generate faster code.